# Coordinating overobj and toolbar buttons to set pointer in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

This [post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/171483) shows how to use the overobj function to set the pointer to change over the axes part of a gui. The problem is that this will override the pointer shape set by the zoom or pan toolbar buttons. I can test for various toolbar buttons being on like this:

```
  if (strcmp(handles.zoom.State, 'off'))
    obj_han=overobj('axes');
    if ~isempty(obj_han)
      set(handles.figure1,'Pointer','cross');
    else
      set(handles.figure1,'Pointer','arrow');
    end
  end
```

But that requires adding a new test for every tool button in the toolbar, which seems like a formula for error. How does zoom, for example, set the pointer? Is there a better way to integrate changing the pointer with the way the toolbar buttons make the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the undocumented [`uimode` and `uimodemanager`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/enabling-user-callbacks-during-zoom-pan) to get the current `uimode` and if the current `uimode` is empty, then none of the tools are active.

```
manager = uigetmodemanager(gcf);

% Only alter the pointer if the CurrentMode is empty
if isempty(manager.CurrentMode)
    if ~isempty(obj_han)
        set(handles.figure1, 'Pointer', 'cross')
    else
        set(handles.figure1, 'Pointer', 'arrow')
    end
end
```

I would retrieve the `uimodemanager` *outside* of your callback and pass it explicitly to the callback so you don't have to retrieve it every time.

Comment: that works, but prompts an additional question. My gui has an axes obj that I then imshow('pic.bmp') on top of. The default behavior is to turn off visibility of the axes obj, which hides the axes from overobj. OK, turn it back on, but now I get tick marks outside my image. I can turn them off with axes.XTick = [] (and same for Y), but is there a more graceful way to do this? 

Also, should the first line of your code use gcbf instead of gcf?

Comment: @Llaves The only way to accomplish that with an axes is what you have done. You can use `gcbf` if you prefer. The snippet just shows that you retrieve the `uimodemanager` from the figure. How you get that figure handle is up to you.